# best way to format ngModel for input type date

Tags: html, angularjs, angular-ngmodel, html-input

I know `input[date]` require date type from JSON, then I format ngModel value with `new Date(json.date)` , it's works

`2015-11-15` become `Mon Nov 15 2015 02:00:00 GMT+0200 (CEST)`

But I need the value be a string `2015-11-15` for my webservice.

What is the best way to be ensure it works with input but keep available for my webservice please?

Answer (score 0):

In whatever controller that calls your web service, you can use the same `date:` filter used in the dom `{{myDateObjectThatNeedsToBeFormatted | date: 'yyyy-MM-dd'}}` in your controller.

Simply inject the `$filter` service!!!

```
//Controller
angular.controller("myControllerThatCallsAWebservice", ["$scope","$filter", "myWebService", myNamedControllerFn]);

function myNamedControllerFn($scope, $filter, myWebService) {
   $scope.myDateVariableThatIsBoundToNgModel = new Date(2013, 9, 22);

   $scope.isolatedFnForConvertingYourDateToDesiredString = function alwaysNameFunctionsForDebuggingFn() {
       return $filter('date')($scope.myDateVariableThatIsBoundToNgModel, "yyyy-MM-dd")
   }

   myWebService.webServiceCallToDoStuff(
       $scope.isolatedFnForConvertingYourDateToDesiredString()
   );  
}
```